# Почему при передаче Entity через generiс дублируются артибуты и в БД сохраняется не то, что нужно?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

Есть класс **NestedSetBuilder**
В нем есть метод **MakeRootAsync**

```
public async Task<TEntity> MakeRootAsync<TEntity>(TEntity ownerNode) where TEntity: NestedSetEntity
        {
            _operation = OperationMakeRoot;
            ownerNode.Lft = 1;
            ownerNode.Rgt = 2;
            ownerNode.Depth = 0;
            await _db.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(ownerNode);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return ownerNode;
        }
```

Есть базовый класс **NestedSetEntity**

```
public class NestedSetEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int Lft { get; set; }
        public int Rgt { get; set; }
        public int Depth { get; set; }
        public Guid? Tree { get; set; }

    }
```

Есть класс-наследник **Category**

```
[Table("categories")]
    public class Category: NestedSetEntity
    {
        public Category()
        {
            Visible = true;
            CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
            UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        }

        [Column("id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(256)]
        [Column("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Column("lft")]
        public int Lft { get; set; }

        [Column("rgt")]
        public int Rgt { get; set; }

        [Column("depth")]
        public int Depth { get; set; }

        [Column("tree")]
        public Guid? Tree { get; set; }

        [Column("visible")]
        public bool Visible { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("created_at")]
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [Column("updated_at")]
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

Есть метод, где вызывается **makeRootAsync**

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Categories()
        {
            //var res = await _dnsParserService.ParseCategoriesAsync();
            var res = await _categoryParserService.ParseCategoryListAsync();

            var categoryIds = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var categoryListResItem in res)
            {
                if (categoryIds.TryGetValue(categoryListResItem.CategoryFirstTitle, out var parentCategory)) continue;
                var node = Map(categoryListResItem, "CategoryFirstTitle");
                var addedCategory = await _nestedSetBuilder.MakeRootAsync(node); // Тут вызов
                categoryIds[categoryListResItem.CategoryFirstTitle] = addedCategory.Id.ToString();
            }
            return Ok(res);
        }
```

В базе значения **Lft**, **Rgt**, **Depth** заполнены нулями
[image: то, что в базе]

В Debugger-e видно что поля дублируются (Отдельно поля базового класса и отдельно наследника)
[image: То, что показывает Debugger]

Подскажите, как это исправить?

Comment: А при чём тут передача через Generic? Поля как бы в любом случае будут дублироваться, потому что вы их создали два раза...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Но если я в базовом классе их не определелю, то не смогу использовать LINQ в NestedSetBuilder

Comment: а зачем вы их определяете в производном классе, если они уже есть в базовом? Но если уж хотите переопределять поля, то делайте их виртуальными с переопределением, а то сейчас вы их не переоределяете, а скрываете.

Comment: @tym32167 переопределяю затем, чтобы указать атрибуты для соответствия полей в классе колонкам в БД

Comment: 1) вы не переопределяете, вы скрываете. 2) так укажите аттрибуты в базовом или сделайте пеоеопределение по нормальному

Comment: @tym32167 указал нужным полям virtual в базовом классе и override в дочернем и это помогло. Благодарю за помощь

Comment: @tym32167 стоит оформить ответом?

Comment: @PashaPash готово

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите переопределять поля, то делайте их виртуальными с переопределением, а то сейчас вы их не переоределяете, а скрываете.

Например:

```
public class NestedSetEntity
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Category: NestedSetEntity
{
    public override Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```